# Button to replace html content

Tags: javascript, html, button, replace, getelementbyid

I would like to replace on button click some content in a div. But somehow it doesn't work. What am I missing here? Another script with the same `.getElementByID` works perfectly, which I used in an `onload` of an `iframe` on the same page.

**Here is my code for the button:**

```
<div class="checkout_shape" id="content1">Content</div>
<div><button onclick="GoToShipping()">Click Me</button></div>

<script>
//Working function
function LoadCart(){
document.getElementById("content1").innerHTML ="<iframe src='/cart' width='100%' height='900px' frameborder='0' scrolling='yes' z-index='-5'></iframe>";
}

//Not working function
function GoToShipping(){
  document.getElementById("content1").innerHTML ="<iframe src='/shipping' width='100%' height='900px' frameborder='0' scrolling='yes' z-index='7'></iframe>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: This code is working normally. https://jsfiddle.net/5jf0xhmd/

Comment: Are you selecting elements by class name?

Comment: @Chaska: No I just use css to style the div.

Comment: Thanks guys! Could it be, that the onload function of the other iframe somehow overwrites the 'GotoShipping' function? But I guess it should be a one time action?